# Pure javascript way of swapping input values on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a pure javascript way of swapping input values when you click a div? You can see a working example with jquery here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qo33n4q0/)

```
<div id="swap">Click me</div>
<input id="one" value="One"/>
<input id="two" value="Two"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#swap").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var fromVal = $("#one").val();
        var toVal = $("#two").val();

        $("#one").val(toVal);
        $("#two").val(fromVal);
    });
</script>
```

There are many examples of doing this with jquery, but I haven't found a pure javascript way of doing it.

Comment: `$("#id").val()` is the same as `document.getElementById('id').value`. What's the problem?

Comment: everything that jQuery does, you can do with plain JavaScript. So the question isn't "is there a way" but "how do I do this in vanilla JS"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and I'd always add "is it worth doing?" Meaning is 1 line of jQuery abstracting 10,000 lines of JS :)

Comment: And `$("#swap").click(func)` is equivalent to `document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", func)`. These are all very simple translations, there's nothing fancy going on in your handler.

Comment: But why down vote the man?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course.

```
<button id="swap">Click me</button>
<input id="one" value="One"/>
<input id="two" value="Two"/>

<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("swap");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var from = document.getElementById("one"),
          to = document.getElementById("two");
      if(!!from && !!to) {
        var _ = from.value;
        from.value = to.value;
        to.value = _;
      } else {
        console.log("some input elements could not be found");
      } 
    });
</script>
```

The equivalent of jQuery's $(...) is actually document.querySelector, so we could have used `document.querySelector("#swap")`, too, but if you have an element id, there is a dedicated `getElementById` that's faster, so you typically don't bother with query selecting.

Also note that the equivalent to jQuery's `click` is actually `.addEventListner`, not `.onclick`. The first lets you register arbitrarily many handlers, the latter is an exclusive handler that gets overwritten if you ever try to add a second, third, etc. event handler. It's from an older version of JavaScript, don't use it =)

The swap is then simply the same as with any programming language, where you get your two inputs, cache one of them, reassigned the one you just cached, and them assign the cached value to the other input.

```
cached <- a.val
a <- b.val
b <- cached
```

Finally, note this code doesn't say it's "text/javascript". In HTML5, this is not a thing you say anymore. Anything that's just `<script>` is assumed javascript *unless* you explicitly mention another type.

Comment: Finally, someone posted with `addEventListener`

Comment: let's hope everyone else notices that too. That's a lot of answers with the ancient `onclick` O_o

Comment: I'll second that - I used `onclick` out of (bad) habit in my answer, too. +1 for reminding everyone what's the proper way to add click handler.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. Yes, I know about the script type declaration, but shouldn't it be used for older browsers?

Comment: @take2 even older web browsers will default to JavaScript if no other script type declaration is detected, and they will actually do so faster than if they have to stop and parse the script type declaration.

Comment: older browsers tend to assume javascript if you leave the `type` attribute off, because they have lax parsing for HTML (if you use an xhtml doctype, you probably still need it, but there should be no reason for an xhtml doctype these days). That said, "older browsers" is pretty much exclusively IE for versions of windows that Microsoft doesn't even support anymore, and things like old IOS safari and Android Chrome/Webview. I think of those, only IE might have "real" problems.

Comment: @Thriggle OK, good to know, I saw some contradicting info about that and always used the longer declaration, just in case.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No, there's no xhtml in my case, so there's no need for script type obviously.

Comment: One thing to note, if you're going to use `addEventListener` instead of the more clobbery `onclick` is that it's not supported in older versions of Internet Explorer (IE8 and down). To be functionally equivalent to the jQuery `.click()` approach, you'll want to check whether `addEventListener` is supported and if it's not, use `attachEvent` instead.

Comment: with the footnote that IE6-8 are only found (in metrics that matter) on machines that are running Microsoft operating systems that are no longer supported by them (such as windows 98 or windows XP). Check what your users are actually on and then make an informed decision.

Comment: `document.querySelector("swap")` is wrong, you're looking fot `<swap>` tags. I think you meant to write `document.querySelector("#swap")`

Comment: @Mike one of the reasons IE8 support still comes up for Windows 7+ machines is that certain sites/web applications (especially intranet sites) will coerce the browser into a "compatibility mode" that mimics an older version of Internet Explorer. IE9 won't recognize `addEventListener` when it's running in IE8 Standards mode.

Comment: @Thriggle sure, but the chances that those intranet applications use vanilla JS instead of jQuery are pretty much zero, but even if you did use plain JS, `on...` is still not the answer. You'd use [attachEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then again, if your job is to maintain an IE8-compatible intranet site, you're going to have 99 problems but "how do I even listen for events" won't be one. You're maintaining IE8 code. You already suffered through that learning curve.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, everything the jQuery is doing in your example has a corresponding approach in pure JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("swap").onclick =
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputOne = document.getElementById("one");
    var fromVal = inputOne.value;

    var inputTwo = document.getElementById("two");
    var toVal = inputTwo.value;

    inputOne.value = toVal;
    inputTwo.value = fromVal;
  };
```

```html
<div id="swap">Click me</div>
<input id="one" value="One" />
<input id="two" value="Two" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept this as the correct answer, since it was the first one.

Comment: @take2 you really should use `addEventListener`--it's the modern approach and the better equivalent, as explained in the [Pomax answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29990199/361762)

Comment: I actually recommend accepting Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans's answer, since he provides a few more details and uses the more modern `addEventListener()` approach (which lets you have multiple event listeners attached to an event, at the expense of not working in older versions of Internet Explorer).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I updated my answer to use `addEventListener()` instead of assigning function to ancient `onclick` element property. For explanation: please see (and upvote!) accepted answer by **@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans**, who was the first user in this question who posted answer using this approach.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qo33n4q0/3/

Code is pretty analogical to jQuery version posted above:

```
var inputOne = document.getElementById('one');
var inputTwo = document.getElementById('two');
var swapButton = document.getElementById('swap');

swapButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // optional - unless our button is a link/submit input
  var fromVal = inputOne.value;
  var toVal = inputTwo.value;

  inputOne.value = toVal;
  inputTwo.value = fromVal;
});
```

I'm not sure about your motivation for switching to vanilla JS, but most of the time it's easier to just use jQuery. Unless you care about performance.

Nice, entertaining (but actually serious and enlightening, in a way) read about this whole issue (frameworks vs. vanilla): [Vanilla JS framework](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: Thank you. It's for performance reasons. On those pages I don't have any other reason to load jquery, so this is a simple way to improve performance.

Comment: note that `onclick` is a deprecated way of handling events, and is *not* the equivalent to jQuery's `.click`. The modern way (and what jQuery uses) is to use `.addEventListener("click", handlerFn)`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, you bet me to it - I was just editing my answer to use this method as well. All credits to you (as you can see), you were the first skipping obsolete `onclick` :-). Kudos for that!

Comment: haha. I haven't used `on...` handling since JS added proper event handling to the point that sometimes I need to remember it's even a thing =)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("swap").onclick = function(evt) {
    var tmp, one, two;
    evt.preventDefault();
    one = document.getElementById("one");
    two = document.getElementById("two");
    tmp = one.value;
    one.value = two.value;
    two.value = tmp;
}
```

Comment: note that `onclick` is a deprecated way of handling events, and is *not* the equivalent to jQuery's `.click`. The modern way (and what jQuery uses) is to use `.addEventListener("click", handlerFn)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pure javascript version of it:

HTML

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
document.getElementById("swap").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var fromVal = one.value;
    var toVal = two.value;
    one.value = toVal;
    two.value = fromVal;
});
```

```html
<div id="swap">Click me</div>
<input id="one" value="One"/>
<input id="two" value="Two"/>
```

Comment: note that `onclick` is a deprecated way of handling events, and is *not* the equivalent to jQuery's `.click`. The modern way (and what jQuery uses) is to use `.addEventListener("click", handlerFn)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var swap = document.getElementById("swap");
swap.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var one = document.getElementById("one");
    var two = document.getElementById("two");
    var fromVal = document.getElementById("one").value;
    var toVal = document.getElementById("two").value;

    one.value=toVal;
    two.value=fromVal;

    return false;
}, !0);
```